# ClearInterval not clearing setInterval after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

*** EDIT ***
I have tried this..

```
StartPollingServer: () => {
    return setInterval(() => {
    MyTest.PollingServer();
    }, 1000);
}
```

and also have tried

```
StartPollingServer: () => {
    const a = 
    setInterval(() => {
    MyTest.PollingServer();
    }, 1000);
    return a;
},
```

and still the variable test comes back empty

I am unsure why the clearInterval isn't clearing the setInterval after running for 10 seconds, can someone point out why the clearInterval isn't working

```js
var MyTest = MyTest || {};
MyTest = {
  StartPollingServer: () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      MyTest.PollingServer();
    }, 1000);
  },
  PollingServer: () => {
    console.log("Polling Server");
  },
  StopPollingServer: (f) => {
    clearInterval(f);
    f = null;
  }
}

var test = MyTest.StartPollingServer();

setTimeout(() => {
  MyTest.StopPollingServer(test);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: You are not returning anything in `StartPollingServer`, so f has an invalid value

Comment: Also note that `f = null;` is superfluous here, you might as well remove that line entirely because it doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález, I don't think I follow you, if I put the setinterval in a variable and return that variable in the StartPollingServer, I still get nothing being returned in the test

Comment: @Chris: Can you update the question to include that attempt?  Because currently the problem is simply that `StartPollingServer` doesn't return anything, so `test` is `undefined`.

Comment: @David, ok, will do that now

Comment: The `return` attempt you tried should work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vfo16g9w/

Comment: @Chris: Your attempt [works](https://jsfiddle.net/0gme4a9k/).  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: f in the chat...

Answer (score 0):

Your `f` is not the correct interval handle.

You need to store the result of `setInterval` into some property and then use that into the `clearInterval`.

```js
let f = null
const obj = {
  op1: () => {
    f = setInterval(...)
    // More instructions
  },
  op2: () => { 
    clearInterval(f)
    // More instructions
  }
}
```

In my example I used a variable outside the object but you may use `this` and `function` to be able to reference the `f` property within your object

Comment: Also `var MyTest = MyTest || {};
MyTest = {` is simpler written `var MyTest = {
  StartPollingServer: () => { ...`

Comment: This is completely wrong.
Accessing the interval directly won't change anything. He already stores it inside a variable and it's then passed as a parameter.

He just needs to return a value in StartPollingServer

Comment: @Ramsey there are ZERO return statement in the code he's provided, therefore no storage happens. And none of the arrow functions are single instruction; all of them open the brackets